# HTTPS Caching proxy server for S3

Tags: proxy, https, http

I'm looking for a way to cache objects contained from S3 to a local proxy server.

But, unlike solutions I've seen written in Internet blogs which cache to one specific S3 host only, I need to allow access to a range of hosts.

More specifically, in code I have a request that contains all the required headers for authorization.  I want to send that request to the desired server via a proxy and have the proxy perform the request.

NGINX reverse proxies might work, but I don't know how to configure it to make it dynamically determine where to send the request.  Normally the CONNECT header does this and forms a tunnel.  From then on in, it would seem like I can't cache the results but I'm not sure.  I certainly tried it with go code but haven't gotten it to work as I would expect.

Is it possible?

Comment: What about https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/ ?

Comment: @ceejayoz - thanks but totally the wrong product for us.

Comment: It would probably help, then, to explain why you need this and why the Storage Gateway is so wrong for it. What's the goal here?

Comment: Actually it might work.  But the problem there is I have to run esx.  That's not an option for us.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/storagegateway/getting-started/ indicates it also supports MS Hyper-V, if that's an option.

Comment: @ceejayoz - unfortunately not.